# Do I need to file a DBA for a mobile application / website published using my LLC's name?

Tags: united-states, internet

I have formed an LLC in my state. I am currently developing a mobile application under a different name, but published as my LLC. *Note, the mobile application itself will not generate revenue directly.* I am also developing a website under a similar name "[Application Name] *Portal*" that is business facing. This site will be available on a subscription basis.

Do I need to file a DBA for accepting payments on the business facing portal? If I do all transactions under the name of my LLC, would I still need a DBA?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you do all transactions under the name of your LLC, you do not need a DBA.

You may want to consider a trademark/service mark application for your separately named app (at least under state law in the state where your LLC is organized), which is cheap and easy under state law (although it provides less protection than a federal filing).